# Migration Script is creating foreign key constraint but not generating value from reference column

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, migration, constraints, dbeaver

System information:

- Operating system (distribution) and version: Mac Catalina
- DBeaver version: 7.1.2
- Database name and version: Postgresql
- Express Server
- VSCode

I have been working with 2 tables.  The first table's id needs to be linked by foreign key to the second table's "folder_id".  My migration script created the tables as planned.  When seeding the database, I am unable to get the values from the foreign key constraint to propagate from the reference column (id) in the (folder_id) column.  Currently the "folder_id" column is saying NULL after I seed the database.  I am trying to get the values in folder_Id to be the values from the id column in the folders table

here is a screenshot of both tables: [view of both tables in DBeaver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZp7J.png).

Here is the migration script I used:

```
 CREATE TABLE noteful_folders (
    id int4 PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    hex_id VARCHAR,
    title TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE noteful_notes (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    hex_id VARCHAR,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    modified TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    folder_hex_id VARCHAR,
    folder_Id int4,
    content TEXT
);

ALTER TABLE noteful_notes ADD CONSTRAINT note_fk FOREIGN KEY (folder_id) REFERENCES public.noteful_folders(id);
```

Here are the two seed scripts I used:

notes seed:

```
INSERT INTO noteful_notes (hex_id, title, modified, folder_hex_id, content)
VALUES
    ('cbc787a0-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Dogs', '2019-01-03T00:00:00.000Z', 'b0715efe-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit blandit purus convallis vehicula. Vestibulum enim augue, auctor a diam eget, scelerisque laoreet eros. Proin id maximus nisi, sed rhoncus mi. Suspendisse eu arcu volutpat, tempor nisl at, pretium erat. Nullam a elementum lorem. Mauris aliquam ante a libero eleifend pretium. Donec ante odio, consectetur vel nisl quis, semper bibendum velit. Sed magna turpis, placerat eget arcu vitae, pellentesque dignissim mi. Nunc ullamcorper dolor mi. Ut tortor orci, laoreet et vestibulum a, ornare sed quam. Integer id quam dui. Fusce et consectetur nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere augue id mattis.'),
    ('d26e0034-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Cats', '2018-08-15T23:00:00.000Z', 'b07161a6-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit blandit purus convallis vehicula. Vestibulum enim augue, auctor a diam eget, scelerisque laoreet eros. Proin id maximus nisi, sed rhoncus mi. Suspendisse eu arcu volutpat, tempor nisl at, pretium erat. Nullam a elementum lorem. Mauris aliquam ante a libero eleifend pretium. Donec ante odio, consectetur vel nisl quis, semper bibendum velit. Sed magna turpis, placerat eget arcu vitae, pellentesque dignissim mi. Nunc ullamcorper dolor mi. Ut tortor orci, laoreet et vestibulum a, ornare sed quam. Integer id quam dui. Fusce et consectetur nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere augue id mattis.'),
    ('d26e01a6-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Pigs', '2018-03-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'b07161a6-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit blandit purus convallis vehicula. Vestibulum enim augue, auctor a diam eget, scelerisque laoreet eros. Proin id maximus nisi, sed rhoncus mi. Suspendisse eu arcu volutpat, tempor nisl at, pretium erat. Nullam a elementum lorem. Mauris aliquam ante a libero eleifend pretium. Donec ante odio, consectetur vel nisl quis, semper bibendum velit. Sed magna turpis, placerat eget arcu vitae, pellentesque dignissim mi. Nunc ullamcorper dolor mi. Ut tortor orci, laoreet et vestibulum a, ornare sed quam. Integer id quam dui. Fusce et consectetur nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere augue id mattis.'),
    ('d26e0570-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Birds', '2019-01-04T00:00:00.000Z', 'b0715efe-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit blandit purus convallis vehicula. Vestibulum enim augue, auctor a diam eget, scelerisque laoreet eros. Proin id maximus nisi, sed rhoncus mi. Suspendisse eu arcu volutpat, tempor nisl at, pretium erat. Nullam a elementum lorem. Mauris aliquam ante a libero eleifend pretium. Donec ante odio, consectetur vel nisl quis, semper bibendum velit. Sed magna turpis, placerat eget arcu vitae, pellentesque dignissim mi. Nunc ullamcorper dolor mi. Ut tortor orci, laoreet et vestibulum a, ornare sed quam. Integer id quam dui. Fusce et consectetur nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere augue id mattis.'),
    ('d26e0714-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Bears', '2018-07-12T23:00:00.000Z','b0715efe-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit blandit purus convallis vehicula. Vestibulum enim augue, auctor a diam eget, scelerisque laoreet eros. Proin id maximus nisi, sed rhoncus mi. Suspendisse eu arcu volutpat, tempor nisl at, pretium erat. Nullam a elementum lorem. Mauris aliquam ante a libero eleifend pretium. Donec ante odio, consectetur vel nisl quis, semper bibendum velit. Sed magna turpis, placerat eget arcu vitae, pellentesque dignissim mi. Nunc ullamcorper dolor mi. Ut tortor orci, laoreet et vestibulum a, ornare sed quam. Integer id quam dui. Fusce et consectetur nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere augue id mattis.'),
    ('d26e0854-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Horses', '2018-08-20T23:00:00.000Z', 'b07161a6-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit blandit purus convallis vehicula. Vestibulum enim augue, auctor a diam eget, scelerisque laoreet eros. Proin id maximus nisi, sed rhoncus mi. Suspendisse eu arcu volutpat, tempor nisl at, pretium erat. Nullam a elementum lorem. Mauris aliquam ante a libero eleifend pretium. Donec ante odio, consectetur vel nisl quis, semper bibendum velit. Sed magna turpis, placerat eget arcu vitae, pellentesque dignissim mi. Nunc ullamcorper dolor mi. Ut tortor orci, laoreet et vestibulum a, ornare sed quam. Integer id quam dui. Fusce et consectetur nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere augue id mattis.'),
    ('d26e0980-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Tigers', '2018-03-03T00:00:00.000Z', 'b07162f0-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit blandit purus convallis vehicula. Vestibulum enim augue, auctor a diam eget, scelerisque laoreet eros. Proin id maximus nisi, sed rhoncus mi. Suspendisse eu arcu volutpat, tempor nisl at, pretium erat. Nullam a elementum lorem. Mauris aliquam ante a libero eleifend pretium. Donec ante odio, consectetur vel nisl quis, semper bibendum velit. Sed magna turpis, placerat eget arcu vitae, pellentesque dignissim mi. Nunc ullamcorper dolor mi. Ut tortor orci, laoreet et vestibulum a, ornare sed quam. Integer id quam dui. Fusce et consectetur nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere augue id mattis.'),
    ('d26e0aac-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Wolves', '2018-05-16T23:00:00.000Z','b07162f0-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit blandit purus convallis vehicula. Vestibulum enim augue, auctor a diam eget, scelerisque laoreet eros. Proin id maximus nisi, sed rhoncus mi. Suspendisse eu arcu volutpat, tempor nisl at, pretium erat. Nullam a elementum lorem. Mauris aliquam ante a libero eleifend pretium. Donec ante odio, consectetur vel nisl quis, semper bibendum velit. Sed magna turpis, placerat eget arcu vitae, pellentesque dignissim mi. Nunc ullamcorper dolor mi. Ut tortor orci, laoreet et vestibulum a, ornare sed quam. Integer id quam dui. Fusce et consectetur nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere augue id mattis.'),
    ('d26e0bce-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Elephants', '2018-04-11T23:00:00.000Z', 'b07161a6-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit blandit purus convallis vehicula. Vestibulum enim augue, auctor a diam eget, scelerisque laoreet eros. Proin id maximus nisi, sed rhoncus mi. Suspendisse eu arcu volutpat, tempor nisl at, pretium erat. Nullam a elementum lorem. Mauris aliquam ante a libero eleifend pretium. Donec ante odio, consectetur vel nisl quis, semper bibendum velit. Sed magna turpis, placerat eget arcu vitae, pellentesque dignissim mi. Nunc ullamcorper dolor mi. Ut tortor orci, laoreet et vestibulum a, ornare sed quam. Integer id quam dui. Fusce et consectetur nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere augue id mattis.'),
    ('d26e0f48-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lions', '2018-04-26T23:00:00.000Z', 'b0715efe-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit blandit purus convallis vehicula. Vestibulum enim augue, auctor a diam eget, scelerisque laoreet eros. Proin id maximus nisi, sed rhoncus mi. Suspendisse eu arcu volutpat, tempor nisl at, pretium erat. Nullam a elementum lorem. Mauris aliquam ante a libero eleifend pretium. Donec ante odio, consectetur vel nisl quis, semper bibendum velit. Sed magna turpis, placerat eget arcu vitae, pellentesque dignissim mi. Nunc ullamcorper dolor mi. Ut tortor orci, laoreet et vestibulum a, ornare sed quam. Integer id quam dui. Fusce et consectetur nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere augue id mattis.'),
    ('d26e1074-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Monkeys', '2018-02-05T00:00:00.000Z', 'b07162f0-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit blandit purus convallis vehicula. Vestibulum enim augue, auctor a diam eget, scelerisque laoreet eros. Proin id maximus nisi, sed rhoncus mi. Suspendisse eu arcu volutpat, tempor nisl at, pretium erat. Nullam a elementum lorem. Mauris aliquam ante a libero eleifend pretium. Donec ante odio, consectetur vel nisl quis, semper bibendum velit. Sed magna turpis, placerat eget arcu vitae, pellentesque dignissim mi. Nunc ullamcorper dolor mi. Ut tortor orci, laoreet et vestibulum a, ornare sed quam. Integer id quam dui. Fusce et consectetur nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere augue id mattis.'),
    ('d26e11a0-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Bats', '2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'b0715efe-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit blandit purus convallis vehicula. Vestibulum enim augue, auctor a diam eget, scelerisque laoreet eros. Proin id maximus nisi, sed rhoncus mi. Suspendisse eu arcu volutpat, tempor nisl at, pretium erat. Nullam a elementum lorem. Mauris aliquam ante a libero eleifend pretium. Donec ante odio, consectetur vel nisl quis, semper bibendum velit. Sed magna turpis, placerat eget arcu vitae, pellentesque dignissim mi. Nunc ullamcorper dolor mi. Ut tortor orci, laoreet et vestibulum a, ornare sed quam. Integer id quam dui. Fusce et consectetur nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere augue id mattis.'),
    ('d26e12c2-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Turtles', '2018-09-11T23:00:00.000Z', 'b07161a6-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit blandit purus convallis vehicula. Vestibulum enim augue, auctor a diam eget, scelerisque laoreet eros. Proin id maximus nisi, sed rhoncus mi. Suspendisse eu arcu volutpat, tempor nisl at, pretium erat. Nullam a elementum lorem. Mauris aliquam ante a libero eleifend pretium. Donec ante odio, consectetur vel nisl quis, semper bibendum velit. Sed magna turpis, placerat eget arcu vitae, pellentesque dignissim mi. Nunc ullamcorper dolor mi. Ut tortor orci, laoreet et vestibulum a, ornare sed quam. Integer id quam dui. Fusce et consectetur nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere augue id mattis.'),
    ('d26e1452-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Zebras', '2018-08-13T23:00:00.000Z', 'b07161a6-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit blandit purus convallis vehicula. Vestibulum enim augue, auctor a diam eget, scelerisque laoreet eros. Proin id maximus nisi, sed rhoncus mi. Suspendisse eu arcu volutpat, tempor nisl at, pretium erat. Nullam a elementum lorem. Mauris aliquam ante a libero eleifend pretium. Donec ante odio, consectetur vel nisl quis, semper bibendum velit. Sed magna turpis, placerat eget arcu vitae, pellentesque dignissim mi. Nunc ullamcorper dolor mi. Ut tortor orci, laoreet et vestibulum a, ornare sed quam. Integer id quam dui. Fusce et consectetur nulla. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere augue id mattis.');
```

folders seed:

```
INSERT INTO noteful_folders (hex_id, title)
VALUES
  ('b0715efe-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Important'),
  ('b07161a6-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Super'),
  ('b07162f0-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1', 'Spangley');
```

My question: what would I need to do to get the folder_id column in the notes table to reflect the values from the id column in the folders table?  Do I need to put a placeholder of some sort inside the seed script for the notes table to get the values to populate correctly from the folder table's id column?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not link screenshots.  Can you please paste the text from your screenshots as text into code blocks in your answer?

The `folder_hex_id` column in table `noteful_notes` violates the principle of relational theory.  The `noteful_notes` table should contain only the `folder_id` column.  Oddly, your model's violation of this principle makes it very simple to fix the already seeded data.  Issuing this will correct your data, but this is absolutely not the right way to do your seeding.

```
update noteful_notes
   set folder_id = f.folder_id
  from noteful_folders f
 where f.hex_id = noteful_notes.folder_hex_id;
```

I assume you are not using an ORM, and please do not correct me if I am wrong since  ORMs are the devil :-)

My suggestions are for you to remove the `folder_hex_id` column from `noteful_notes`, define `folder_id` in `noteful_notes` as `folder_id not null references noteful_folders(id)`, make your seeding procedure load `noteful_folders` before loading `noteful notes`, and seed your `noteful_notes` table thusly:

```
with indata (hex_id, title, modified, folder_title, content) as (
  values ('<your note hex id1>', '<your note title1>', '<your timestamp1>',
          '<your folder title1>', '<your post content>1'),
         ('<your note hex id2>', '<your note title2>', '<your timestamp2>',
          '<your folder title2>', '<your post content2>')
)
insert into noteful_notes (hex_id, title, modified, folder_id, content)
select i.hex_id, i.title, i.modified, f.id, i.content
  from indata i
  join folder f 
    on f.title = i.folder_title
;
```

I assume you have a good reason for keeping `hex_id` values with your notes and folders.  Please mention in the comments if you do not have a good reason.

If you would rather link the notes to the folders with the `hex_id` in your data, then it should be pretty clear how to substitute `folder_hex_id` for `folder_title`.

Comment: @Mike_Organek Just replaced the screenshots with code where possible...I left the screenshot of the database, wasn't sure the best way to put that in a post like this!


I'm going to avoid doing it the way advised against...I am new to databases and SQL!


I need the hex_ids for the app that it's designed for.  Was given a boilerplate that used them for routing...that's the reason they are there.  I thought I might need the relating folder_hex_id on each of the notes for tweaking the app on the front end, but can probably do away with them and be fine.  Simpler is preferred!